# automatic power source selection

Tags: audio

I would like to power a speaker using two separate power sources and I would like the selection to default to 18V AC-DC wall adapter first, if available.  If that source is not available (unplugged), I would like the circuit to instantaneously (will explain this in a bit) switch to the alternative power source which is a 3.7v lipo battery.  The 18v source should feed the following:

Option 1: 30W 12-24V input amp -> speaker

Option 2: 18V to 4.2V buck converter -> 3.7V protected lipo battery -> 3.5-5V input 3W amp -> speaker

Both options are driving the same speaker.  Option 1 should be the default but if the 18v source is unplugged i would like the circuit to switch to option 2 in a timely manner. Meaning that if the speaker is playing music and being driven by the amp in option 1 and power is suddenly unplugged, I would like for the circuit to quickly switch to the battery and continue from there.  Additionally, when the 18V is connected, the circuit in option 2 should be charging the battery but power should not be fed to the 3w amplifier. Conversely, if the buck converter is not on, the battery should be feeding the 3W amp (any additional protection necessary here if buck converter fails while 18v power source is connected?).

I come from a mechanical background and only do this as a hobby so please understand that my electrical knowledge is limited to basics. I was looking into schottky diodes but I'm not sure what the selection criteria is and where in the circuit they should be put. Any help or additional resources on this topic is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

[image: overall circuit]

Comment: Can you provide a better system diagram?

Comment: please see above.  it is probably wrong and missing many components but it is intended just for informational use. I do not plan on building any of the components (amps, buck converter) -- they are all pre-fabricated. I would just like to connect them safely and efficiently together as a system via switches or diodes.

Comment: Your diagram needs some work .I couldnt edit it probably because my screenname has an element of truth.

Answer (score 1):

from your written descrioption, here;s what to do.

find a relay that operates from 18V (most relays marked 24V will work just fine, or ones marked 12V with a resistor half the coil resistance in series) you'll need a relay with two change-over contats "DPDT" or two relays with single change over contacts.

what you do is use wire the relay coil(s) parallel  to the power input to the 10W amplifier, and put a switch before that so you can cut power to the 10W amplifier and the relays.

in the output from the Li-Po put the contacts of the first relay that are 'on' whern the power is off.

in the input to the speaker use the other set of relay contacts to select which amplifier to connect the speaker to..

with the 18V present and the switch on the relay turn off the 1W amplifier and connects the speaker to the 10w amplifier, if you turn off the switch the 10W amplifier and the relay are unpoweed, the onpiwered relay selects the 1W for the speaker and connects the 1W amplifier to the ip-po battery.

the buck converter that charges the lipo is connected to the 18V input so it's on anytime the power is connected.

you'll probably want to add a switch that turns off the 1W amplifier and possibly also the 10W amplifier too. (switching both with one switch requires a dual pole switch)

Comment: so with a DPDT relay, you are suggesting i wire the 18V leads in parallel with the DPDT coils and amp1.  Then wire the normally closed pins in parallel and between the battery output leads and amp2.  My confusion is what do with the normally open pins-- are you suggesting i wire them in parallel to the output signal from amp1 and hard wire the output signal from amp2 directly to the speaker crossover network?

Comment: ah no, one half of the relay turns amp2 on and off, the other half connects the loundspeaker to the apropriate amplifier.